# Is the sum of a discrete and a continuous random variable continuous or mixed?

Tags: self-study, distributions, random-variable

If $X$ is a discrete and $Y$ is a continuous random variable then what can we say about the distribution of $X+Y$? Is it continuous or is it mixed?

What about the product $XY$?

Answer (score 16):

Suppose $X$ assumes values $k \in K$ with discrete distribution $(p_k)_{k \in K}$, where $K$ is a countable set, and $Y$ assumes values in $\mathbb R$ with density $f_Y$ and CDF $F_Y$.

Let $Z = X + Y$. We have
$$ \mathbb P( Z \leq z) = \mathbb P(X + Y \leq z) = \sum_{k \in K} \mathbb P(Y \leq z - X \mid X = k) \mathbb P(X = k) = \sum_{k \in K} F_Y(z-k) p_k,$$ which can be differentiated to obtain a density function for $Z$ given by 
$$ f_Z(z) = \sum_{k \in K} f_Y(z-k) p_k.$$

Now let $R = X Y$ and assume $p_0 = 0$. Then
$$ \mathbb P(R \leq r) = \mathbb P(X Y \leq r) = \sum_{k \in K} \mathbb P(Y \leq r/X) \mathbb P(X= k) = \sum_{k \in K} F_Y(r/k) p_k,$$
which again can be differentiated to obtain a density function.

However if $p_0 > 0$, then $\mathbb P(X Y = 0) \geq \mathbb P(X = 0) = p_0 > 0$, which shows that in this case $XY$ has an atom at 0.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with probability mass function $p_X : \mathcal{X} \to [0,1]$, where $\mathcal{X}$ is a discrete set (possibly countably infinite). Random variable $X$ can be *thought* of as a continuous random variable with the following probability density function

$$f_X (x) = \sum_{x_k \in \mathcal{X}} p_X  (x_k) \, \delta (x - x_k)$$

where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

If $Y$ is a continuous random variable, then $Z := X+Y$ is a **hybrid** random variable. As we know the probability density functions of $X$ and $Y$, we can compute the probability density function of $Z$. Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the probability density function of $Z$ is given by the **convolution** of the probability density functions $f_X$ and $f_Y$

$$f_Z (z) = \sum_{x_k \in \mathcal{X}} p_X  (x_k) \, f_Y (z - x_k)$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Yeah, I'm also curious about the downvote

Comment: @Yair I haven't downvoted it, but it looks like a misleading and incomplete answer.  Simply writing a distribution in terms of a Dirac delta doesn't make it continuous!   This answer is also limited in that (a) it does not consider general discrete distributions, which may have a countable infinity of atoms and (b) it implicitly assumes $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @whuber I agree with (b). However, it is said that a discrete RV "can be thought of as...", so I think it adds an interesting view.

Comment: @whuber If $X$ can only take values in a discrete set, calling it discrete is natural, but every PMF can be written as a PDF. My answer can be easily generalized to discrete distributions with infinite support. The only objection of yours that has actual weight is the implicit assumption of independence. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I look forward to the improvements.  I especially hope you will eliminate the claim that suggests all discrete variables are continuous!

Comment: @whuber I can claim that a 6-faced die has a PDF with 6 Dirac deltas. What matters is the support. The complement of the support is a matter of taste.

Comment: This is why I wrote that your answer is misleading. Because the question concerns the distinction between discrete and continuous distributions--and that distinction is a matter of mathematical definition, not "taste"--your efforts to confuse the two are likely to be less than helpful.

Comment: @whuber I edited my answer. Please let me know if you find any errors or unwarranted assumptions. Also, since $\{1,2,\dots,6\} \subset \mathbb Z \subset \mathbb R$, modeling the throw of a $6$-faced die as a discrete RV is a matter of (good) taste. However, when adding discrete and continuous random variables, thinking of discrete random variables as continuous ones is natural. My answer has a strong signal processing flavor, and it may be misleading to those who never set foot in an electrical engineering department, but it's not mathematically incorrect, to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/217903/68124) assumes that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Here is a solution which does not need that assumption.

**Edit:** I am assuming that "continuous" means "having a pdf." If continuous is instead intended to mean atomless, the proof is similar; simply replace "Lebesgue null set" with "singleton set" in what follows.

---

Let the support of $X$ be the countable set $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\dots\}$. I will use

> **Lemma:** A random variable $Z$ is continuous if and only $P(Z\in E)=0$ for all Borel measurable sets $E$ with Lebesgue measure zero.

*Proof:* Use the [Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem). $ \square$

To prove $X+Y$ is continuous, take any null set $E$, and note that
$$
P(X+Y\in E)=\sum_k P(\{Y+x_k\in E\}\cap \{X=x_k\})\le \sum_k P(Y+x_k\in E)
$$
But $Y+x_k\in E$ if and only if $Y\in E-x_k$. The shifted set $E-x_k$ is still Lebesgue null. Since $Y$ is continuous, this means $P(Y+x_k\in E)=0$, so the above summation is zero, proving $X+Y$ is continuous.

For the question of products, the same logic applies as long as $P(X=0)=0$. If $P(X=0)=1$, then $XY$ is discrete with $P(XY=0)=1$. Otherwise, $XY$ is a nontrivial mixture.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $X$ takes values in a countable set $\{n_i\}_{i=1,2,\dots}$. If $Y$ is continuous, for every real number $t$
$$
{\rm P}(X+Y=t) = \sum_i{\rm P}(X=n_i,Y=t-n_i) =0,
$$
since for all $i$ we have $\{X=n_i,Y=t-n_i\}\subseteq \{Y=t-n_i\}$ and ${\rm P}(Y=t-n_i)=0$.

Therefore $X+Y$ is continuous.

If ${\rm P}(X=0)=0$ then $XY$ is continuous too, and the proof is similar:
$$
{\rm P}(XY=t) = \sum_i{\rm P}(X=n_i,Y=t/{n_i}) =0.
$$
However, in general the product $XY$ can be discrete (for instance if $X=0$), continuous (as we have seen) or mixed (take $Y$ with uniform distribution in $(0,1)$, and let $X=0$ if $Y\le 1/2$, $X=1$ if $Y>1/2$).