# Average Log Likelihood of Sum of Discrete Random Variable plus Continuous Uniform Noise

Tags: probability, distributions

I am looking at the proof given in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.01844.pdf) constituting lines (3) to (6) but am stuck on the first line. The setup is as follows:

Consider $X \in \mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ with a discrete probability distribution $P(x)$, uniform noise $U \in [0,1]$ and noisy data $Y=X+U$ with density $p(y)$. Suppose we model $Y$ with density $q(y)$. Then we have (first line of proof):

$$\int p(y)\text{log} q(y)dy = \sum_{x} P(x) \int_{0}^{1} \text{log} q(x+u)du$$

I am truly stuck with this inequality; I'm sure there is some rule of probability at work here, but I really just don't see what (other authors citing this proof assert that it is "easy" so I'm assuming there is just some rule I'm missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, this should make sense : to compute the expected value of $\log q(Y)$, you can look at the expected value of $\log q (x+U)$ for each $x\in \mathcal X$ and average the result by the "mass" of each $x$.

The mathematical equivalent of this intuitive explantion is provided by the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) (LTE), according to which we have
$$\int\log q(y) p(y)\ dy=:\mathbb E[\log q(Y)] \stackrel{(LTE)}{=} \mathbb E_X \big[\mathbb E_U[\log q(X + U)\mid X]\big] $$

Now, since $U\sim\text{Uniform}([0,1])$, we can compute for all $x\in\mathcal X$ :
$$\mathbb E_U[\log q(X + U)\mid X=x] = \int_0^1 \log q(x+u )\ du$$
From which it follows that
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[\log q(Y)] &= \mathbb E_X \big[\mathbb E_U[\log q(X + U)\mid X]\big] \\
&= \sum_{x\in \mathcal X} P(x)\mathbb E_U[\log q(X + U)\mid X=x]\\
&= \sum_{x\in \mathcal X} P(x) \int_0^1 \log q(x+u )\ du
\end{align*} $$
As desired.

Comment: You can also see here for a way to compute the density $p$ by differentiating the CDF : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217897